# UiView in UIScrollView leaving the bottom space in iPhone 7 plus simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

[while using scrollview view in it is not expanding in iPhone 7Plus simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugbwf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below . . hope it will work !

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```